# How to copy blobs between containers?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

```
public void CopyBlobsBetweenContainers(string sourceContainerName, string targetContainerName, IEnumerable<string> blobsToCopy)
{
    foreach (var sourceBlobName in blobsToCopy)
    {
        _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetPageBlobReference(sourceBlobName);
        if (!sourceBlob.Exists())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SafeFormatter.Format(CloudLocalization.Culture, CloudLocalization.CannotCopyBlobDoesNotExist, sourceBlobName));
        }

        var targetBlob = targetContainer.GetPageBlobReference(sourceBlobName);
        if (targetBlob.Exists())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SafeFormatter.Format(CloudLocalization.Culture, CloudLocalization.CannotCopyTargetAlreadyExists, sourceBlobName));
        }

        _logger.Debug("Copying blob '{0}' from container '{1}' to '{2}'", sourceBlobName, sourceContainerName, targetContainerName);

        targetBlob.Create(sourceBlob.Properties.Length);
        targetBlob.StartCopy(sourceBlob);
    }

    _logger.Debug("Copy blobs finished");
}
```

If I have my page blobs inside folder(CloudBlobDirectory) in source container
I don't want to copy folder I want to copy just my page blobs to target container. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [TransferManager class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.datamovement.transfermanager_methods.aspx) included in the [Azure Data Movement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/) library.

You can copy each blob by executing:

```
await TransferManager.CopyAsync(sourceBlob, targetBlob, isServiceCopy: false);
```

Note that if you choose to use service side copy ('isServiceCopy' set to true), Azure (currently) doesn't provide SLA for that. Setting 'isServiceCopy' to false will download the source blob locally and upload it to the target blob.

Comment: Just a note, this is in the Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library, which is the library that underlies the AzCopy command-line utility. See https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/ and https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement for more information.

Comment: Is the Data Movement Library included in the Azure SDK?  I was thinking it was a standalone thing...

Comment: @BenV Correct, it is a standalone library. I've updated my answer.